# Duplicate tab in Console2

Tags: console2

I was wondering if there is a way to open up a new tab in Console2 and have it open in the same directory as the current tab?

I am developing a Laravel app and I have a server running on one tab and when I need to migrate and other things, I need a new tab.

I know I can stop the server migrate and I know it only takes a couple seconds to cd into the directories, but I was just wondering if there is an option for this.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to try ConEmu? It has that feature and many others.

Comment: I have looked at ConEmu, I was just familiar with Console2 and I was wondering if this feature is available either inherently or through a plugin, etc. Anyways, Thanks! I shall look at ConEmu and maybe give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

[ConsoleZ](https://github.com/cbucher/console) is a fork of Console2. To all intents and purposes looks about the same albeit better rendered.

I've just come across it and it seems pretty good (given only 15 minutes use).

Most importantly, it does what you want: **Clone in new tab**.